# Change component when button is clicked reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to change the component after button is clicked. I have defined a changeComp() function in the class of my component and when the button is clicked I want to route it to the wallet-connect component but it doesnt seem to work. Kindly, help me out what am I missing here or why this practise is wrong?

```
changeComp(){
return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/wallet-connect" component={WalletConnect} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );}

<button className="btn w-100 mt-3 mt-sm-4" onClick={(event) => this.changeComp(event)} type="submit">Sign In</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return JSX from an event handler and expect it to be rendered into the DOM.

In your case you need to render the "/wallet-connect" `Route` into your main router and in the `changeComp` callback invoke an imperative navigation.

Main router:

```
<Switch>
  ...
  <Route path="/wallet-connect" component={WalletConnect} />
  ...
</Switch>
```

In component with button:

```
changeComp(event) {
  this.props.history.push("/wallet-connect");
}

<button
  className="btn w-100 mt-3 mt-sm-4"
  onClick={(event) => this.changeComp(event)}
  type="submit"
>
  Sign In
</button>
```

If the component doesn't have the [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) injected then you'll need to decorate it with the [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component.

Suggestion:

Since the button is a `type="submit"` and if it's rendered within a form, then just issue the imperative navigation from the form's `onSubmit` handler.

```
submitHandler = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
  this.props.history.push("/wallet-connect");
}

...

<form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
  ...
  <button
    className="btn w-100 mt-3 mt-sm-4"
    type="submit"
  >
    Sign In
  </button>
</form>
```

If the button is ***not*** part of a form then specify the button type to be a "button" so it doesn't interfere with any form elements.

```
<button
  className="btn w-100 mt-3 mt-sm-4"
  onClick={(event) => this.changeComp(event)}
  type="button"
>
  Sign In
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
changeComp(){

const history = useHistory();

return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/wallet-connect" component={WalletConnect} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
<button className="btn w-100 mt-3 mt-sm-4" onClick={(event) => history.push("/wallet-connect")} type="button">Sign In</button>
        );}
```